# How to get a list of all integer points in an n-dimensional cube using python?

Tags: python

Given a cube with the coordinates from (-x, -x, -x, ...) to (+y, +y +y, ...), x,y>0, how do I get a list of all integers with short and easy to read code?

So far I have:

```python
list((x,y,z) for x in range(-x,y) for y in range(-x,y) for z in range(-x,y))
# has the dimension hardcoded

list(itertools.product(*[np.arange(-x, y)]*dim))
# difficult to understand what is going on
```

Is there a more intuitive solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second solution seems perfectly fine, though I'd do it this way instead:

```
list(itertools.product(range(-x, y), repeat=dim))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just encapsulate your "hardcoded" version in a function, and pass the dimensions as arguments

```
def cube_points(x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2): #This describes any rectangular prism
    return [(x,y,z) for x in range(x1, x2+1) for y in range(y1, y2+1) for z in range(z1, z2+1)]
```

Where `x1` and `x2` are the endpoints of the line formed by projecting the cube onto the x axis, etc.

EDIT: For an n-dimensional cube

```
from itertools import product
def ndcube(*args): #accepts a list of 2-tuples
    return list(product(*map(lambda x: range(x[0], x[1]+1), args)))
```

Comment: Sry, I meant the dimensions of space. So the second one will give me two dimensional points if set dim to 2.

Comment: @MrZ Oops, I totally missed "n-dimensional".  Not a problem.

Comment: @MrZ i added a solution for any hyperrectangle.  Looking at it, I think your second solution, with Stefan Pochmanns modification, is as good as you're going to get

Comment: Nice generalisation. Although I would probably use `*x` instead of `x [0], x [1]`. But then again it starts getting a bit hard to follow.

Comment: @MrZ I avoided that because python range objects are right-exclusive `[x, y)`, which we don't want. A cube of volume one `ndcube((1, 2), (1, 2))` would report only one point unless we added one to the right side of our `range`

Comment: Ah, I forgot. Then your version is the better one.